# Question about proper usage of the word "castrate"

Tags: word-usage

I'm looking for the word you would use to describe the act of removing the genitals of a man.

From my research, I have come up with "castrate" "geld" "neuter" "emasculate" and "desex", but these all seem to describe the removal of the testicles only.

There is the word "penectomy" but that is the surgical removal of the penis, and seems to describe a formal, voluntary or medically necessary procedure. Is there a specific term for removing the penis and the testicles? The word I am looking for, if it exists, would describe the involuntary removal, such as during an attack.

Comment: The expression used to define  what you are describing probably is "male genitals mutilation."

Comment: @Josh61 **genital** singular I should think but otherwise you're completely right.

Comment: bilateral orchiectomy, if everything else is left as it was.

Comment: Chopadichophomy

Comment: I would have thought _eunuchisation_ would express this, but every dictionary definition I can find just says that's a synonym of _castration_ and/or _emasculation_. None of them, however, seems to have any opinion on whether castration/emasculation/eunuchisation entails removing only the testes or all the external reproductive organs.

Comment: @Dylan: be aware that all these comments are wrong. (But _chopadichophomy_ might catch on...)

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're looking to express is perhaps amputation.  You could then speak of genital amputation or the act of amputating the genitals, or metaphorically, manhood, masculinity, or any of a variety of other euphemisms for male generative equipment.